# I have a large list of dataframes and need to extract multiple based on their names

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a large list called "all_input" that contains 13 data.frames as such:

```
Name                  Type                Value
all_input             list[13]            List of length 13
  113_red.csv         list[649 x 14]      A data.frame with # rows and # columns
  blue_123.csv        list[389 x 14]      A data.frame with # rows and # columns
  blue_4.csv          list[428 x 14]      A data.frame with # rows and # columns
  greenblue_123.csv   list[789 x 14]      A data.frame with # rows and # columns
  greenblue_4.csv     list[132 x 14]      A data.frame with # rows and # columns
  greenblue_5.csv     list[245 x 14]      A data.frame with # rows and # columns
```

I need to read just the files containing "blue" in the name, not "greenblue", just "blue".
I tried

```
blue <- grepl( "^blue", all_input$Name )
```

and this returns a value "blue" logical (empty). For context, after extracting the blue data.frames, I am going to select specific columns and rbind them into a new data.frame.
str(my data) returns:

```
> str(all_input)
List of 13
 $ 113_red.csv:'data.frame':    6490785 obs. of  14 variables:
  ..$ state_and_county_fips_code: int [1:6490785] 88180 88180 88180 88180 88181 88181 88181 88181 88182 88182 ...
  ..$ tribal_name               : Factor w/ 14 levels "","Coeur d'Alene Tribe of the Coeur d'Alene Reservation, Idaho",..: 12 12 12 12 2 2 2 2 6 6 ...
  ..$ st_usps_cd                : Factor w/ 55 levels "","AK","AL","AR",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ county_name               : Factor w/ 1939 levels "","Abbeville",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ data_category_cd          : Factor w/ 1 level "NP": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ scc                       : num [1:6490785] 2103008000 2302002100 2102008000 2302002200 2102008000 ...
  ..$ emissions_type_code       : Factor w/ 5 levels "","C","H","M",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ aircraft_engine_type_cd   : logi [1:6490785] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ emissions_op_type_code    : logi [1:6490785] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ data_set_short_name       : Factor w/ 72 levels "2011ADEM","2011AKDEC",..: 51 51 51 51 52 52 52 52 53 53 ...
  ..$ pollutant_cd              : Factor w/ 198 levels "100027","100414",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ description               : Factor w/ 198 levels "1-Methylphenanthrene",..: 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
  ..$ total_emissions           : num [1:6490785] 0.000448 0.07679 0.006822 0.369756 0 ...
  ..$ uom                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "LB","TON": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ blue_123.csv    :'data.frame':   3985783 obs. of  14 variables:
  ..$ state_and_county_fips_code: int [1:3985783] 42097 42031 42031 36097 51540 23009 72103 54037 25013 36119 ...
  ..$ tribal_name               : logi [1:3985783] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ st_usps_cd                : Factor w/ 16 levels "CT","DC","DE",..: 10 10 10 9 13 6 11 16 4 9 ...
  ..$ county_name               : Factor w/ 431 levels "Accomack","Adams",..: 284 101 101 361 90 174 267 200 171 414 ...
```

and so on. 'Type' is a list, and 'Value' is a list of data.frames.

Comment: Is it a data.frame with three columns where 'Type', 'Value' are `lists`.  Please show the `str(yourdata)`

Comment: Looks like it is `grep("blue", names(all_input))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can filter by the `names` of the 'all_input' using `grep`, loop over the `list` elements with `map`, and `select` the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(all_input[grep("^blue", names(all_input))], ~ 
            .x %>%
                select( state_and_county_fips_code,  tribal_name ))
```

note: using `grepl` and "^blue" omit data.frames named "greenblue" from the selection.